# How to perform tableView.reloadData() without blocking user interaction

Tags: ios, swift

I use a searchBar to search in a list of products and show results in a tableView, I want every character to start new search trip i have accomplished that by some sort of async queues to search for the list of products in the global queue and update tableView in the mainQueue after 500 milliSeconds.

The problem is that while reload table view the user interaction blocks and user can not enter new character before tableview finishes

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    NSObject.cancelPreviousPerformRequests(withTarget: self, selector: #selector(searchOnProducts), object: nil)
    self.searchKeyWord = searchText
    self.perform(#selector(searchOnProducts), with: nil, afterDelay: 0.0)
}

@objc func searchOnProducts() {
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        let returnedProducts = DataHolder.getProductsWithSearch(self.searchKeyWord)
        let productsRef: ThreadSafeReference<Results<Product>>?
        if returnedProducts != nil && returnedProducts!.count != self.searchProducts.count {
            productsRef = ThreadSafeReference(to: returnedProducts!)
        } else if returnedProducts == nil && self.searchProducts.count != 0 {
           productsRef = nil
        } else {
            return
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(500), execute: {
            if productsRef != nil {
                let realm = try! Realm()
                guard let products = realm.resolve(productsRef!) else {
                    return
                }
                self.searchProducts = Array(products)
            } else {
                self.searchProducts.removeAll()
            }
            self.searchTV.reloadData()
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Why *after 500 ms*?

Comment: to can cancel the selector if user enter another character befor reloading the tableview

Comment: Reloading the table view should be reasonably fast. How are you doing this search? What precisely is blocking the UI and for how long? It’s hard to diagnose the source of the problem without knowing precisely what your code is doing. Give us [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Rob take a look on my code.

Comment: You’re doing your realm inquiry from the main thread. Can you do that from the global queue, instead? The updating of the UI (and the model) should happen on the main thread, but retrieving the results should be done on background thread, if you can.

Comment: how explain please

Answer (score 0):

You are doing work on the RealmDB on your main thread. You should probably move that to the global queue as well. Only call `reloadData()` on the main thread then.

EDIT: In your `cellForRow`, you should also access the results array in the global queue and then update the cell content on the main thread. This way you should hopefully be able to avoid the threading error you receive.

Additionally: 
Did you try to profile your app? That should give you a better idea which lines of code take long. Are there maybe any other time consuming things you do when you create the tableview cells?

Comment: when i tried to make this i have a crash "Realm accessed from incorrect thread" as i update the date source of ftableview in global thread and reload table view in main thread

Comment: Okay, you are correct. Can you please share the code which you use for loading the tableviewcells? And try profiling your app. It should give you an idea.

Comment: @MAHMOUDOMARA - The [Realm docs](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#threading) say “The only thing you have to be aware of is that you cannot have multiple threads sharing the same instances of Realm objects. If multiple threads need to access the same objects they will each need to get their own instances (otherwise changes happening on one thread could cause other threads to see incomplete or inconsistent data).”

Comment: loading cell data is simply filling some labels, I doesn't have idea how to profile my app but i will work on how to do that

Comment: I know that and i think that I handled that correctly but the lag happens while drawing the tableview or by other means while reloadData() I think